# Parceler with not basic type android

Tags: android, parceler

I am implementing parceler using lib by [link](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler)

It working when i using basic type: int, String, double, ...
But now, i have some field with specific type like: context, custom class ?
So I must do something with problem? need help

Comment: `Parcelable` is done to share model objects between activities/fragments. You shouldn't even think to parcelable or serialize a Context object.

Comment: but it run error with, "unable to find read/write generator for type context:content"

Answer (score 0):

if you go the library description you can see the number of supported parameter listing there

for Custom you need to annotated class with

```
@Parcel
```

Comment: i cannot assign anotation @Parce in content object ?

Comment: You can configure a class in a library by using @ParcelClass